# JS: Interpolate a variable into a variable

Tags: javascript, interpolation

In the code below, I am trying to set the text for my 4 buttons. Would appreciate a helping hand with:

```
allButtons[i].innerHTML = btn${i};
```

and particularly with

```
btn${i}
```

I am  trying to pass to .innerHTML the text stored above, but so far failed to do it. Most attempts I tried led to:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Question: how can I interpolate a variable into a variable in JS? The code:

```
  var btn0 = "Load tasks from server";
  var btn1 = "Load tasks from Local Storage";
  var btn2 = "Create tasks";
  var btn3 = "Edit tasks";

  var allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

  function setText( btn0, btn1, btn2, btn3, allButtons ) {
    var allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

    for (i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
      console.log(i);
      allButtons[i].innerHTML = btn${i}; // interpolation issue
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why not make an array and all your problems are solved?

Comment: To find the gap of my understanding of interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a variable that way. The easiest solution is:

```
var btnTexts = ["Load tasks from server", "Load tasks from Local Storage", "Create tasks", "Edit tasks"];

var allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

function setText( allButtons ) {
    for (i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        allButtons[i].innerHTML = btnTexts[i];
    }
}

// Then call the function using: setText(allButtons);
```

Comment: Yep, that indeed works, but I was learning interpolation. It has no practical value, only learning. Though, thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in js.

- An alternative is using an object with the set of texts, and use the string interpolation (**[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**) to build the specific `key` + `i`.
- Use `textContent` instead because is only text.

```js
var btns = {
  btn0: "Load tasks from server",
  btn1: "Load tasks from Local Storage",
  btn2: "Create tasks",
  btn3: "Edit tasks"
}

function setText(allButtons) {
  for (i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
    allButtons[i].textContent = btns[`btn${i}`];
  }
}

var allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
setText(allButtons);
```

```html
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
```

Comment: I could do this in Ruby, piece of a memory. Got your idea, very useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 interpolation works inside back-tick quotes strings, but it doesn't work in expressions like that.

The only thing that would work sort of the way you want -- and it's certainly not recommended -- would be to do an `eval` on an interpolated string. As someone else said, you're better off with an array.

NOT RECOMMENDED:

```
allButtons[i].innerHTML = eval(`btn${i}`);
```

Comment: Clear, thx. Interesting and good to know.

Comment: Interesting enough to up-vote my answer to make up for the fact that someone decided to down-vote it? :)

Comment: Nope, its viceversa. That is possible to do in Ruby. The fact that smb downvoted your answer does not influence the fact that your answer clarified my question.